# Selecting the App pool an application installs to

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

Right I'm not too sure If I worded the question correctly but I'm in need of help. I'm a trainee software engineer and I've  been placed on a role to replace someone going away for a while. We have existing ASP.NET MVC apps installed on some IIS servers and every time we re-deploy/install them, it install the application using the default app pool, when we need it to be installed on 'xAppPool'.

Is this a setting that needs to be changed within the code, Web.config, or the installer? I'm not too sure and I'd much prefer if I didn't have snobby users complaining how I've got the title 'Software engineer', like in previous questions I've asked.

Apologies If I've not given enough description or there's another thread (I couldn't find it) - I'll happily shed any light on any questions you may have.

Lewis

Comment: How is the website deployed, with WebDeploy?

Comment: Nope, afraid to say we use a custom deployment tool. I didn't design this, only use it. I take it the solution would be to modify the tool and select the app pool within this?

Comment: Yes, you will need to update the custom script.  It may actually be easier to change over to WebDeploy.  What all does the script do?

Comment: See this installer is already in place and we've mostly just manually altered which application pool it's on, it's not much of a problem but solving this would save the tedious work.

Comment: It's in place for a client and to be honest I don't think it's viable changing the type of installer, just modifying the existing one. So from your comments, I take it as the current installer needs updating. Is there nothing that can be done within the config files? 

thanks for your help by the way

Comment: I understand.  Take some time to try WebDeploy.  We did two years ago and loved it.  We use it for all of our deployments now.

Comment: You can't magically get it done without modifying he installer and since you described none about that, this question is impossible to be answered.

Comment: Well if you look at the description of my question. I ask is this done within the installer or elsewhere, you've just answered that question. So it's clearly not impossible. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

This is super easy to do with WebDeploy.  Just specify the IIS Site name which points to the correct site/app pool.  You can add the following MSBuild argument if you are using a TFS build or MSBuild.exe:

```
/p:DeployIisAppPath="[Website name in IIS]"
```

Or if you want to change it at deploy time you can use the MSDeploy `SetParam` argument:

```
-setParam:IIS Web Application Name="[Website name in IIS]"
```

Comment: As I've just mentioned to @chief27 , I don't think changing to webdeploy is viable as this for a project with a client and this installer has been in place for two years. (Also I'd have no clue how to change to WebDeploy...) 

Thanks for your help though, I'll mark it up for others to see